# Copy/Paste part of Excel workbook to workbooks that are not currently open

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a section of an Excel workbook to ~3500 other workbooks. Because of the number of workbooks, running a macro on each isn't feasible.

Is there a way to copy that piece and paste it to the other workbooks without having them open?

Comment: You can't copy/paste to a file without opening the file. Common sense should tell you that; how would you **paste** without the file being open?

Comment: Assuming you know which part of the workbooks to copy to, and it's exactly the same place, it's conceivable that you could open in a different program, copy and save. Of course, you could just write a loop that opens each workbook, pastes the required code, and closes - 3500 times, or for each workbook in a folder.

Comment: `Is there a way to write a macro (or any other piece of code really) that can copy that piece and paste it to the other workbooks without having them open?` It depends on the set up of your data. If it is arranged database like (with fields and rows) I think it is possible. In short, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomato,
Unfortunately, as @Ken White and @L42 have both pointed out, in order to edit a file you must, at least on some level, open it (i.e. load it into memory). What's worse is that unless you're willing to manipulate the xml or binary data directly (not advised), you're going to have to use Excel to open the .xlsx file for you, which takes time.

This does not, of course, mean that you have to do in manually. For instance:

```
Sub DataToOtherWorkbooks()
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Rng = "A1:A2"
    Set SourceRange = Range(Rng)

    StrFile = Dir("C:\ExcelWorkBooks\*.xlsx")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Debug.Print StrFile
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set TargetWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\ExcelWorkBooks\" & StrFile)
        TargetWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Rng).Value(11) = SourceRange.Value(11)
        TargetWb.Save
        TargetWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

The above code will loop through all files in the folder ExcelWorkBooks with a .xlsx extension and populate them with the data located in the designated range of your source workbook.

As mentioned earlier, however, this will take some time. When I ran it on 100 workbooks (from my laptop) it took an average of 0.54 seconds per workbook. So, in your case, with 3,500 workbooks you're looking at about 31 minutes. Not exactly light speed, but certainly better than doing it by hand. Hope this is of use to you. Please ask if you have further questions.

**SUPPLEMENT**

Tomato, in response to your comment, to transfer the format, including the merged or unmerged nature of the cells in your range you would use:

```
TargetWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Rng).Value(11) = SourceRange.Value(11)
```

I've updated the original code to reflect the change. This should take care of it for you, but let me know.

Comment: This worked! However, some of the cells of the source Workbook were merged or had a different alignment. Could this be copied to the others as well? Thanks

Comment: @Mystic Tomato, I've supplemented my answer in response to your comment. Should you have any trouble, just ask.