# Copy paste data into multiple workbooks in a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I enter data everyday into a workbook called 'Sample Data'. I need to copy and paste the same data into multiple workbooks in a folder (named Test). I also need to save and close all these 100 files that I've pasted the data into.

Just for clarification, I am manually entering data into the workbook 'Sample Data.xlsx' and I want this data to be copied into multiple workbooks saved in the Test folder. Ideally, I wouldn't want to open and close all these files because they would slow down my computer but it seems to me that there is no alternative to this - i.e. to copy paste & save this new data I would need to open and close all 100 files.

Update: this is the modified code, thanks to @Krishna

```
Sub Copydate()

Dim Path            As String
Dim FileName        As String
Dim Wkb             As Workbook
Dim WS              As Worksheet

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Path = ("/Users/devanshiruparel/Desktop/IFA Internship/Test")
FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
Do Until FileName = ""
    Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
    For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
    Workbooks("Sample Data.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:O17").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    Next WS

    Wkb.Save
    Wkb.Close True
    FileName = Dir(Path, vbNormal)
Loop
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you gave the particular coding too much effort, but with that aside - It's not clear from your question, do you want each worksheet to be opened and saved in a separate workbook or in separate worksheet and then saved in a single workbook?

Comment: Also, opening and saving 100 files of the same data is going to clog pretty much anyone's computer!

Comment: There are **many** existing examples on this site and others on how to automate copy/pasting data between workbooks.  For example, [**here's a bunch of similar questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel+copy+paste+workbook).  Also, see "**Related**" → → → →  (right side of this page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy/Paste part of Excel workbook to other workbooks without opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088389/copy-paste-part-of-excel-workbook-to-other-workbooks-without-opening)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't keep the Sample file and other required files in the same folder

```
Sub Copydate()

    Dim Path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim WS              As Worksheet

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path =  'paste the folder path here
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
'Change below file address as per your requirement

        Workbooks("Sample Data.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9:A11").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        Next WS

        Wkb.Save
        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response! This code doesn't seem to be working though :/
Basically, I'm trying to copy a range of cells (that I manually edited) from one workbook (Sample Data.xlsx) into multiple workbooks (saved in folder Test). - sorry if that wasn't clear! 
Also, do I need to open all the files in the Test folder before they get updated?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to open files while running the macro, the macro will do it automatically. Please provide me your email ID, I will give you the excel macro file as per your requirement.

In the code you edited you did not give the path properly... change it as below (with the drive name)

"C:\Users\devanshiruparel\Desktop\IFA Internship\Test"